# How to debug RSpec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, devise

I'm using devise for authorization purposes in my rails app and got stuck a bit in the unit testing part of development.

```
  it "is invalid with a duplicate email address" do
    User.create(
      name: 'Joe', surname: 'Tester', email: 'tester@example.com', password: 'password123', password_confirmation: 'password123'
      )
    user = User.new(
      name: 'Jane', surname: 'Tester', email: 'tester@example.com', password: 'password123', password_confirmation: 'password123'
      )
    pp user.errors.inspect
    expect(user).to have(1).errors_on(:email)

  end
```

but for that I get `expected 1 errors on :email, got 2`

Can you please suggest how I could figure out what the other error is? I tried `pp user.errors.inspect`, but that wasn't very usefull.

Thank you.

**EDIT**
`pp user.errors.inspect` yielded the following:

```
"#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x000000058016c8 @base=#<User id: nil, name: \"Jane\", surname: \"Tester\", about: nil, level: nil, city: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, email: \"tester@example.com\", encrypted_password: \"$2a$04$TfDBOXXDhUDVuJhPmxbu9eRZsTQ.Om8X5k5YkeDg51e...\", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil>, @messages={}>"
F

Failures:

  1) User is invalid with a duplicate email address
     Failure/Error: expect(user).to have(1).errors_on(:email)
       expected 1 errors on :email, got 2
```

Comment: why wasn't it useful? what did it yield?

Comment: if you just want to print out the errors, you can try user.errors.full_messages ?

Comment: You need to call `valid?` or `save` on the use object before you print the errors (that's when they get created)

Answer (score 0):

This test seems heavy to maintain (if you set another attribute to mandatory, you would have to refactor this test).

You might want to define your test to actually respect its description:

```
it "is invalid without a password" do
  User.create(name: 'Joe', surname: 'Tester', email: 'tester@example.com', password: 'password123', password_confirmation: 'password123')
  user = User.create(email: 'tester@example.com')
  user.should_not be_valid
  user.errors.messages[:email].present?.should be true
end
```